# Samsung devices pausing using OpenSL ES

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-mediaplayer, android-audiomanager

I'm developing an app for Android using OpenSL ES, and it works quite well 'except' on Samsung devices where the audio stutters and pauses quite a bit.  I noticed that the following messages appear in LogCat over and over (again, only on Samsung devices).  Note that I'm not starting/stopping streams myself or changing inputs or outputs.  Just streaming audio data to one output data stream.

Any ideas where this might be coming from?

```
08-25 15:08:22.868: V/AudioPolicyManagerBase(151): stopOutput() output 2, stream 3, session 214
08-25 15:08:22.868: V/AudioPolicyManagerBase(151): changeRefCount() stream 3, count 0
08-25 15:08:22.868: W/AudioPolicyManagerBase(151): stream type [13], return media strategy
08-25 15:08:22.878: W/AudioPolicyManagerBase(151): stream type [14], return media strategy
08-25 15:08:22.878: W/AudioPolicyManagerBase(151): stream type [13], return media strategy
08-25 15:08:22.878: W/AudioPolicyManagerBase(151): stream type [14], return media strategy
08-25 15:08:22.878: W/AudioPolicyManagerBase(151): stream type [13], return media strategy
08-25 15:08:22.878: W/AudioPolicyManagerBase(151): stream type [14], return media strategy
08-25 15:08:22.878: W/AudioPolicyManagerBase(151): stream type [13], return media strategy
08-25 15:08:22.878: W/AudioPolicyManagerBase(151): stream type [14], return media strategy
08-25 15:08:22.878: W/AudioPolicyManagerBase(151): stream type [13], return media strategy
08-25 15:08:22.888: W/AudioPolicyManagerBase(151): stream type [14], return media strategy
08-25 15:08:22.888: W/AudioPolicyManagerBase(151): stream type [13], return media strategy
08-25 15:08:22.888: W/AudioPolicyManagerBase(151): stream type [14], return media strategy
08-25 15:08:22.888: V/AudioPolicyManagerBase(151): getNewDevice() selected device 0
08-25 15:08:22.898: V/AudioPolicyManagerBase(151): setOutputDevice() output 2 device 0000 force 0 delayMs 192 
08-25 15:08:22.898: V/AudioPolicyManagerBase(151): setOutputDevice() prevDevice 0002
08-25 15:08:22.898: W/AudioPolicyManagerBase(151): stream type [13], return media strategy
08-25 15:08:22.898: W/AudioPolicyManagerBase(151): stream type [14], return media strategy
08-25 15:08:22.898: W/AudioPolicyManagerBase(151): stream type [13], return media strategy
08-25 15:08:22.898: W/AudioPolicyManagerBase(151): stream type [14], return media strategy
08-25 15:08:22.898: V/AudioPolicyManagerBase(151): setOutputDevice() setting same device 0000 or null device for output 2
08-25 15:08:22.898: V/AudioPolicyManagerBase(151): checkOutputForStrategy(0002,0002,3)
08-25 15:08:22.898: V/AudioPolicyManagerBase(151): getOutputsForDevice device 0002 -> 0002
08-25 15:08:22.898: V/AudioPolicyManagerBase(151): getOutputsForDevice device 0002 -> 0002
08-25 15:08:22.918: V/AudioPolicyManagerBase(151): startOutput() output 2, stream 3, session 214
08-25 15:08:22.918: V/AudioPolicyManagerBase(151): changeRefCount() stream 3, count 1
08-25 15:08:22.918: W/AudioPolicyManagerBase(151): stream type [13], return media strategy
08-25 15:08:22.918: W/AudioPolicyManagerBase(151): stream type [14], return media strategy
08-25 15:08:22.918: W/AudioPolicyManagerBase(151): stream type [13], return media strategy
08-25 15:08:22.928: W/AudioPolicyManagerBase(151): stream type [14], return media strategy
08-25 15:08:22.928: W/AudioPolicyManagerBase(151): stream type [13], return media strategy
08-25 15:08:22.928: W/AudioPolicyManagerBase(151): stream type [14], return media strategy
08-25 15:08:22.928: W/AudioPolicyManagerBase(151): stream type [13], return media strategy
08-25 15:08:22.928: W/AudioPolicyManagerBase(151): stream type [14], return media strategy
08-25 15:08:22.928: V/AudioPolicyManagerBase(151): getNewDevice() selected device 2
08-25 15:08:22.928: V/AudioPolicyManagerBase(151): setOutputDevice() output 2 device 0002 force 0 delayMs 0 
08-25 15:08:22.928: V/AudioPolicyManagerBase(151): setOutputDevice() prevDevice 0002
08-25 15:08:22.938: V/AudioPolicyManagerBase(151): setOutputDevice() setting same device 0002 or null device for output 2
08-25 15:08:22.938: V/AudioPolicyManagerBase(151): checkOutputForStrategy(0002,0002,3)
08-25 15:08:22.938: V/AudioPolicyManagerBase(151): getOutputsForDevice device 0002 -> 0002
08-25 15:08:22.938: V/AudioPolicyManagerBase(151): getOutputsForDevice device 0002 -> 0002
```

Comment: I'm seeing same issues on an S2 device.  Any solution?